# How to fix a 'replacement has 21 rows, data has 20' Error in R

Tags: r

Here is my data

[image]

I know that I have many missing data which are not available N/A. 
I wrote in Rstudio to determine the clusters for my data after knowing that the optimum number is 3;

```
clusters <- kmeans(testData6[,2:9], 3)
testData6$clusters <- as.factor(clusters$cluster)
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, clusters, value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 21 rows, data has 20
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Just FYI, I've removed the [tag:cluster-computing] tag because it's about a specific type of computing, not about clustering algorithms. From its FAQ: "A computer cluster is a set of connected systems that work together so that in many respects they can be viewed as a single system"